# Make Antd 3.x Popover component accessible via keyboard's tab key

Tags: reactjs, antd, popover

- I would like to use the [Popover](https://3x.ant.design/components/popover/) from Antd 3.x.
- See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-hofstadter-fetfz?file=/index.js), When the focus is on button "Click me" and I click [ENTER] key, the popover shows, all fine till here
- Now when I press [TAB] key again, the focus goes to the next button "Click me 2". Ideally I would like the focus to come to contents of the popover.
- What actually happens: The control goes through all the buttons first and then at the end it comes to the popover contents if the popover is active.
- How can I achieve this? That the focus should come to popover contents immidiately after the button to which the popover belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the tabindex. Though the greater value of the tabindex is not recommended. In your case either you can use like this or you need to handle it with the JavaScript.

[Tabindex- mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Please use the below code:

```
     import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Popover, Button } from "antd";

const content = (
  <div tabIndex={0}>
    <p>Content</p>

    <p>Content</p>
    <Button tabIndex={0}>Content Btn 1</Button>
    <Button tabIndex={0}>Content Btn 2</Button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Popover content={content} title="Title" trigger="click">
      <Button>Click me</Button>
    </Popover>
    <Button tabIndex={1}>Click me 2</Button>
    <Button tabIndex={2}>Click me 3</Button>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```